# Modify Url for Edit Post Screen in Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, urls

Ive looked at the questions that may have already answered what im needing and came up short...Im modifying a plugin and the custom post-type name shows in the url when adding a new post.

But..when I edit a post, the url shows up like this:
/wp-admin/post.php?post=2059&action=edit

With 2059 being the post ID. What I would like is when editing the post for the url to contain the custom post-type name also.

So instead of above, it would show something like:
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=custom_pt_name&post=2059&action=edit
or
/wp-admin/admin.php?post_type=custom_pt_name&post=2059&action=edit

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without modifying WordPress core files.

Comment: Thanks @MikeNGarrett but Im not suggesting removing any parameters, Im trying to add on the custom post type name in the url.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but can you tell me where in the wp codex it specifies that you cannot customize the url for the edit post screen even with your own created post type?

Comment: It's not documented in the codex, but it's definitely documented in the code.